# Same animation for objects one after another

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have some buttons in my menu's and they all have the same animation. I want to play the animation for each button about 50ms after the last button animation has started playing. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your setup looks like and how you start animations.

However, assuming you have a button script `YourButtonScript` with a method `StartAnimation` you can do it in a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like e.g.

```c#
// reference all your buttons in the Inspector via drag&drop
public YourButtonScript[] buttons;

public void StartAnimations()
{
    // Starts the Coroutine
    StartCoroutine(AnimationsRoutine());
}

private IEnumerator AnimationsRoutine()
{
    foreach(var button in buttons)
    {
        // however you start the animation on one object
        button.StartAnimation();

        // now wait for 50ms
        // yield tells the routine to "pause" here
        // let the frame be rendered and continue
        // from this point in the next frame
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    }
}
```

Coroutines in Unity are like temporary little `Update` methods. By using the default `yield return null` you tell Unity to leave the Ienumerator at this point, render the frame and continue in the next frame. Then there are a bunch of usefull tools that allow you to `yield` until a certain condition is fulfilled as in this example [`WaitForSeconds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html) or also [`WaitForSecondsRealtime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html)